# Is it possible to add steps via recording to a pre-recorded Jmeter script?

Tags: jmeter

Let's say you have a complete Jmeter script (created via recording) with all the variables and tokens correctly correlated. Later, you decided to add a few more steps to that script, interleaving these with the previous steps.

Rather than recording a new script from scratch, is it possible to add steps via recording to the previous script?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are multiple ways of doing this:

1. Add another logic controller, i.e. [Recording Controller](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Recording_Controller) to your existing test plan and configure HTTP(S) Test Script Recorder to use it as the "Target Controller"

   [image]
2. There is "Merge" option in File menu entry:

   [image]
3. You can use another JMeter instance and perform recording using [HTTP(S) Test Script Recorder](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/jmeter_proxy_step_by_step.html) or [JMeter Chrome Extension](https://guide.blazemeter.com/hc/en-us/articles/13354690351377-The-BlazeMeter-Chrome-Extension-Record-JMeter-Selenium-or-Synchronized-JMeter-and-Selenium) and once done just copy and paste recorded Samplers into a new test plan like you do with text, images, etc.

   [image]